Why the speed difference in the iteration over a C# jagged array?
I have the following test code using a measurement of the execution speeds:
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Jagged_array_test {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Jagged array test.");

            var width = 1024;
            var height = 512;

            // create a 2D jagged array using "Array" of "Array"-s and fill in with data
            var jagged = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Array), height);
            for (var i = 0; i < jagged.GetLength(0); i++) {
                var row = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(byte), width);
                for (var j = 0; j < row.Length; j++) row.SetValue((byte)0xFF, j);
                jagged.SetValue(row, i);
            }

            // flatten the jagged array to an 1D byte array using 2 slightly different methods
            var data = new byte[width * height];

            var N = 10; // number of tests
            var c = 0;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // Method 1
            var m1 = new List<double>();
            for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                c = 0;
                sw.Restart();
                foreach (Array row in jagged) foreach (byte col in row) data[c++] = col;
                sw.Stop();
                m1.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 1: {m1.Average()} ms");

            // Method 2
            var m2 = new List<double>();
            for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                c = 0;
                sw.Restart();
                foreach (var row in (Array[])jagged) foreach (var col in (byte[])row) data[c++] = col;
                sw.Stop();
                m2.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Method 2: {m2.Average()} ms");

            Console.WriteLine($"Difference: {(m1.Average() / m2.Average()):F3}x");
        }
    }
}

Found out that the iteration over the jagged array used in Method 2 is at least 10-times faster than the one used in Method 1. What's the reason behind?

Never rely on timings at the very beginning of a program. Wrap both tests inside a 2-3 cycles loop, then read the final results.

Or better yet, use something like https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

I agree with you guys, the stopwatch here is just for shortening the demo code.
Anyway I manually exexcuted it many times in a row and the method 2 results were always faster.

BenchmarkDotNet is the defacto standard for benchmarking in .NET, to the point that people will just ignore any differences that weren't produced by a BDN test. You may be looking at the effects of JIT compilation, delayed optimizations that are only applied after the runtime detects a path is executed frequently, random delays on your machine. BDN repeats the tests long enough to ensure it has a statistically stable result and takes care of warmup and cooldown between measurements

Fixed the code with averaging multiple test results...
Anyway, as expected, it gives the same overall result.

foreach has optimizations that apply if the collection is known to be an array of a specific type, or a generic list, i.e. T[] or List<T>. If these optimizations apply it will not generate an enumerator, and instead generate code very similar to a regular for-loop.
Your method 1 uses non generic Array, so may fall into the unoptimized path, generating an enumerator, and likely require boxing of each value due to the the non-generic IEnumerable interface.
Your method 2 casts the arrays , so should fall into the optimized path.
You can use https://sharplab.io if you want to compare the generated assembly between the methods, you can see that your Method1 generate both IL and asm that is a lot longer and more complicated.
In conclusion, try to avoid Array, and prefer T[] or List<T> if you want performance from your collections.

Unfortunately I cannot avoid because this jagged generic Array is coming from a library method. I simply need to use it and interate over it. But your explanation makes sense for me. Thansk for it!
